# Ansible commands work when root, but not when default user. Throws a python PyYAML error only as default user, but then works for root

Tags: python, ansible

I recently ran some PIP commands in my server, and after doing so none of the Ansible commands would work as the default user.  If I try to run any Ansible commands as the default user, I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 4, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import require; require('ansible==2.2.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PyYAML
```

However, if I sudo and then try to run any ansible commands, it seems to work fine.  I think I might have messed something up with the python packages that were installed with PIP, and now they only work for root.

How can I get the default user to be able to run these commands again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyYAML not found when trying to run Ansible scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326155/pyyaml-not-found-when-trying-to-run-ansible-scripts)

Comment: Both questions were asked by me today.  I can delete that other one, as this one has more up-to-date information.

Comment: You can edit your questions to add information without duplicating them.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  I just deleted the previous question as there wasnt really an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  The issue was with permissions when I ran the pip install.  Running 
`chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/` and 
`chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` fixed the issue.